# ERROR: type "jsonb_array_elements" does not exist

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

hi i need the total of array, and return length < 3
and the sql sentence show
ERROR: type "jsonb_array_elements" does not exist

```
{
  data:{
     total:[1,2]
  }
}



 SELECT *
    FROM info in
    WHERE 
        in.info = _TYPE 
        and in.data::jsonb_array_elements #>> '{data,total}' <3
        LIMIT _LIMIT;
```

thanks

Comment: `::` is the cast operator in Postgres so `data::jsonb_array_elements` doesn't make sense. It's unclear to me what result you want exactly. The sum of all the array elements? The sum of array elements that are smaller than 3? The sum of all array elements if the array is shorter than 3? The rows where the sum of all array elements is smaller than 3?

Comment: hi i need the total of elements to get length shorter than 3